# Getting all the non active toggles in a toggle Group

Tags: unity-game-engine, toggle

As it says I want to change image of all the toggle button back to default except for the active one , so i need a method which would get me all the non active toggles. Than in `onClick()` method  of toggle button as the image change, I can shift the default image for everyone and show highlighted image for  the selected one .I can't do it with target graphic and graphic as i don't want to change the full image i have got a background image just want to change that to a highlighted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ToggleGroup doesn't have anything helpful in this scenario, but take a look at this soultion:

**A. Create custom toggle component and use it instead of original Toggle**

```
public class MyToggle : Toggle 
{
    public static Dictionary<ToggleGroup, List<Toggle>> allToggles = new Dictionary<ToggleGroup, List<Toggle>> ();

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

        if (group != null)
        {
            if (!MyToggle.allToggles.ContainsKey(group))
                MyToggle.allToggles.Add(group, new List<Toggle>());

            MyToggle.allToggles[group].Add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**B. Create extension for ToggleGroup:**

```
namespace UIExtensionNS
{
    public static class UIExtension
    {
        public static List<Toggle> GetAllInactiveToggles(this ToggleGroup group)
        {
            if (!MyToggle.allToggles.ContainsKey(group))
                return null;

            List<Toggle> toReturn = new List<Toggle>();

            foreach (Toggle tgg in MyToggle.allToggles[group])
            {
                if (tgg.isOn)
                    continue;

                toReturn.Add(tgg);
            }

            return toReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

**C. Test it :)**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UIExtensionNS;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public ToggleGroup toggleGroup;

    IEnumerator Start () 
    {
        // it is just to ensure it runs after all MyToggle.Start
        yield return null;

        var allInactive = toggleGroup.GetAllInactiveToggles();

        foreach (var tggl in allInactive)
        {
            Debug.Log(tggl.isOn);
        }
    }
}
```